# How to convert Hex to Binary

Tags: go

I am having issues running `encoding/binary`. Here I am trying to convert Hex to Binary but for whatever reason, it doesn't fill the byte slice:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/binary"
)

func main() {
    ui := uint64(18727)
        bn := make([]byte, 8)
        binary.LittleEndian.PutUint64(bn, ui)
        fmt.Printf("%08b\n", bn)
                
}
```

Output:

```
[00100111 01001001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000]
```

What am I missing here?

**Edit**:

Sorry, I removed the code to convert it to decimal so the function is really converting the decimal 18272 to binary.

**Edit2**:
here's the output in decimal. Obviously 39+73!=18727. For whatever reason it only fills up the first two slots of the array.

```
0 = {uint8} 39
1 = {uint8} 73
2 = {uint8} 0
3 = {uint8} 0
4 = {uint8} 0
5 = {uint8} 0
6 = {uint8} 0
7 = {uint8} 0
```

Comment: Where is the hex?

Comment: The output is little endian binary of 18727 decimal, as expected. Maybe you meant 0x18727?

Comment: What is your expected result, and why were you expecting that?

Answer (score 0):

You are encoding a `uint64` value. A `uint64` value has a width of 8 bytes (8 bytes x 8 bits per byte = 64 bits).

Therefore, the binary encoding of this value has 8 bytes.

From the `encoding/binary` package [overview](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#pkg-overview):

> Numbers are translated by reading and writing fixed-size values.